# Is the partition tiling relation transitive?

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, partitions

The following is motivated by an (as of yet) [unanswered question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466637/optimal-colorings) on optimal colorings of graphs. I am convinced that the question below has a positive answer in $\newcommand{\ZF}{{\sf (ZF)}}\ZF$, but so far it has escaped me.

Let $X\neq\emptyset$ be a set, and let $\newcommand{\Part}{\text{Part}}\Part(X)$ be the collection of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of $X$. For $P, Q \in \Part(X)$ we write $P \newcommand{\preq}{\preceq^*}\preq Q$ if there is an injection $\iota: (P \setminus Q) \to (Q \setminus P)$.

**Question.** If $P,Q,R\in\Part(X)$ with $P\preq Q\preq R$, does this entail that $P\preq R$?

**Note.** The answer is easily seen to be positive for $P, Q, R$ finite.

Comment: Do you want to restrict to partitions with the same number (cardinality) of parts? That case seems more related to your other question.

Comment: It seems that $P \newcommand{\preq}{\preceq^*}\preq Q$ iff the cardinality of $P$ is no greater than that of $Q$. But then the "yes" answer is trivial.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: that’s not right. See the example in the question Dominic linked to.

Comment: @SamHopkins : Thank you for your comment. I thought the partitions are finite.

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks for your comment Sam -- I might restrict it to the same cardinality of parts / blocks -- but my hope is that the transitivity for $\preceq^*$ holds even in the general case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Counterexample.** Consider the following partitions of $\omega$.

$P=\{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6\},\dots\}$
$Q=\{\{0,1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\},\dots\}$
$R=\{\{0,1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6\},\dots\}$

Now $|P\setminus Q|=|Q\setminus P|=|Q\setminus R|=|R\setminus Q|=\aleph_0$, so $P\preceq^*Q\preceq^*R$;
but $|P\setminus R|=2$ and $|R\setminus P|=1$, so $P\not\preceq^*R$.

**On the other hand,** if $P\prec^*Q$ means $|P\setminus Q|\lt|Q\setminus P|$, then (at least in **ZFC**, I don't know about **ZF**) we have:
$$P\prec^*Q\prec^*R\implies P\prec^*R;$$
$$P\prec^*Q\preceq^*R\implies P\preceq^*R;$$
$$P\preceq^*Q\prec^*R\implies P\preceq^*R.$$
Here $P$, $Q$, $R$ are just sets, it doesn't matter if they are partitions. It will suffice to prove the first implication, as the others are just restatements. So assume for a contradiction that there are sets $P$, $Q$, $R$ such that $P\prec^*Q\prec^*R\preceq^*P$.

Let $a=|P\setminus(Q\cup R)|$, $b=|Q\setminus(P\cup R)|$, $c=|R\setminus(P\cup Q)|$, $d=|(P\cap Q)\setminus R|$, $e=|(Q\cap R)\setminus P|$, $f=|(P\cap R)\setminus Q|$; so that $|P\setminus Q|=a+f$, $|Q\setminus P|=b+e$, etc. From $P\prec^*Q\prec^*R\preceq^*P$ we have:
$$a+f\lt b+e,\tag1$$
$$b+d\lt c+f,\tag2$$
$$c+e\le a+d,\tag3$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$ are some (finite or infinite) cardinal numbers. From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have
$$a+b+d+f\lt b+c+e+f\tag4$$
since two strict inequalities can be added. If we also had $c+e\lt a+d$, then adding this to $(4)$ we would get the nonsensical $a+b+c+d+e+f\lt a+b+c+d+e+f$. Therefore $c+e=a+d$, but then $b+c+e+f=a+b+d+f$, contradicting $(4)$.